# How to mock "async with" statements?

Tags: python-3.x, mocking, pytest, python-asyncio

I'm trying to write tests for a method that uses "async with" statements (in this case, aioredis's connection pool), i want to mock the connection to redis, but i'm having trouble figuring out how.

Here's what i have so far:

```
from asyncio import Future
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

import pytest

# The thing i'm trying to test
async def set_value(redis, value):
    # Do things
    async with redis.get() as conn:
        await conn.set("key", value)

#My Mock classes
class MockRedis():
    def get(self):
        return MockAsyncPool()


class MockAsyncPool(MagicMock):
    async def __aenter__(self):
        conn = MagicMock()
        f = Future()
        f.set_result(True)
        conn.set = MagicMock(return_value=f)
        return conn

    def __aexit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        pass


# The actual test
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_get_token():
    redis = MockRedis()

    token = await set_value(redis, 'something')
    assert token is not None
```

I run it with:

```
py.test path/to/file.py
```

And i'm getting this error:

> >  await conn.set("key", value)
>
> E TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`__aexit__` needs to also be asyncronous [(needs to return an awaitable)](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__aexit__):

```
async def __aexit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
    pass
```

Without being async it is returning `None` instead of a coroutine so it raises an error, as for the very misleading error message I have created [this issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue29922) to point out that the error message could be greatly improved.